# VM VPN failover

Tags: networking, cisco, virtual-machines, failover

I have a VPN connection from Network1, Host A (VM) to Network2, Host B and Host C. An application in the VM(Host A) is statically configured to communicate with Host B on Network2, i want Host A(Network1) to automatically(failover) route traffic to Host C in case the connection between Host A and Host B breaks to keep the service up continously?

The VPN in Network1 is setup with Cisco ASA.
The VM is windows server.

Please how can i achieve this at the network/transport layer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that comes to mind would be to use an F5 LTM (Local Traffic Manager) VM on Host A. F5 can perform health checks on the viability of the services on Host B and fail over to Host C should B not respond properly. F5 will hook you up with a temporary license for the VM so that you can test it.

Caveat Emptor: F5 is not simple to configure but if you know networking pretty well you could probably figure it out. Also if you ask the local F5 field engineer for help they might be willing to spend some time helping you out.

The process would be something like this:

1. Create an LTM pool. Configure the load balancing type as "priority". Create the remote hosts as pool members with the primary having a lower priority than the fail over.
2. Create a virtual server (essentially just an IP address) of the type "Layer 4" (this has worked for ASA VPNs) and select the pool you created as the backing resource.
3. Create a "monitor" that checks the service readiness on the remote host. Assign this monitor to the pool so that it can verify the readiness of the resource
4. Configure your application to use the virtual server created in step 2.